# How to create and operate very large array in CUPY or GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

I have a python generator that can generate a few hundred/thousand million of rows data. Each row of data is either a list or tuple that may have 7 to 30 elements. Trying to store them as a CuPy 2 dimensional array can be problematic as the array is very large.

On the host, I know such a large array requires a lot of memory that exceeds the RAM physical limit and this will cause the host system to hang. So I can't create such a large array on the host side.

How do I use CuPy to create/handle/compute such a large array?

What is the correct way to use CuPy to handle such large array sizes? Is breaking the array into smaller arrays the way to go? If so, what is the optimal array size that I should use for these smaller arrays? How do I determine this optimal array size? Or does CuPy do this in the background and the programmer does not need to consider this issue?

**Sample code:**

```
from itertools import product
import cupy as cp
import time

def get_sigma( mu ):
    '''Return stdev of supplied mu.'''
    mu_stdev = {  1. : 0.50,
                  2. : 1.00,
                  3. : 1.40,
                  4. : 1.80,
                  5. : 2.10,
                  6. : 2.50,
                  7  : 3.00,
                  8. : 3.50,
                  9. : 3.75,
                 10. : 4.00,
                 11. : 4.25,
                 12. : 4.50,
                }
    sigma = mu_stdev[ mu ]
    return sigma

mumax = 11
#mumax = 12  # Using this value or larger values will exceeds 32GB RAM
mu = [ i for i in range(1,mumax+1,1) ]
print( 'mu', mu )
ndays = 1

for i in range( ndays ):
    start = time.time()
    for j in mu:
        nsamples = 2 * int( get_sigma(j) - 0.5 ) + 1
        print( f'\nResult for mu = {j}: ' )
        print( 'nsamples', nsamples )
        ss = cp.array( [ i[::-1] for i in product( mu, repeat=nsamples ) ] )
        end = time.time()
        print( ss )
        print( f'ss.size={ss.size}, ss.ndim = {ss.ndim}, ss.shape = {ss.shape}' )
        print( f'Time: {(end - start)}sec' )
```

Comment: Was there any particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Can you please share the code so that we can inspect better?

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper See sample code. If `mumax = 12` or more, `ss` becomes too large to create on host with 32GB RAM (system hangs).

Comment: @mkrieger1 See sample code. If `mumax = 12` or more, `ss` becomes too large to create on host with 32GB RAM (system hangs).

Comment: You should try to reduce the complexity as it's now O(n^2). Due to that, python has to keep a track of previous values which is (somehow) memory consuming.

Comment: @YogeshAggarwal Thank you for your valuable comment. :)

Comment: Does it solved your problem?

Comment: @YogeshAggarwal I am still exploring. Integrating that with a strategy of capping the size of `ss` to a certain size that would not exceed RAM. So a few to several `ss` are used.

Comment: what is this `ss`?

Comment: @YogeshAggarwal `ss` is the array created in device (i.e. in GPU) by Cupy. See code. :)